# Загрузка фотографий в asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#, html, sql-server, веб-программирование

Делаю функционал для смены аватарки пользователем. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в asp.net создать функционал для загрузить фотографии пользователем на сервер и её последующее отображение? Может быть, у кого-нибудь уже есть готовый код (не MVC)?

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @DreamChild, загрузка фотографии, в частности аватара, это не учебное задание, а вполне реальный функционал, который встречается практически на любом сайте, поэтому и интересно узнать, нет ли в asp.net какого либо функционала позволяющего легко создавать данный функционал, и как вообще это лучше сделать...

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt я понимаю,  что это не учебное задание.  Просто это такой стандартный комментарий,  который подразумеваю, что было бы неплохо, если бы вы показали,  что уже сделали сами

Answer (score 1):

[Вот на сайте мелкомягких есть отличный мануал по загрузке файлов](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246/ru).

Добавьте условие проверки файлов по маске, чтобы, кроме картинок, ничего больше не грузили.

Отображение картинки (аватара), я думаю, не проблема, в целом надо видеть код, чтобы понять, где, что и как вы отображаете.